Finding all homomorphisms from Z/6Z to Z/15Z
Suppose that I want to find all the ring homomorphisms $\phi$: $Z/6Z \to Z/15Z$. Since $\phi(a+0)=\phi(a)+\phi(0)$, so $\phi(0)$ must be zero. Also, $\phi(a)=\phi(a)*\phi(1)$. Therefore, either $\phi(a)=0$ for all $a\in Z/6Z$, or $\phi(1)=1$. If it is the latter case, $\phi(2)=\phi(1)+\phi(1)=2$, and $\phi(3)=3$, etc. However, $\phi(2)=\phi(4*5)=\phi(4)*\phi(5)=20=5$, and this is a contradiction. So this is impossible, and the only possible ring homomorphism is the one mapping every element in $Z/6Z$ to 0.
Is my approach correct?

Your approach is incorrect. From $\phi(a)=\phi(a)\phi(1)$ you can't conclude $\phi(a)=0$ or $\phi(1)=1$

Ring homomorphisms take $1$ to $1$ by definition. This means that we automatically have $\phi(1) = 1$.

You should check the definition of ring homomorphism you're supposed to use. The usual definition requires $\phi(1)=1$. So it's not something you would need to prove.
